# jQuery math function not working for dynamically added new table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to use jQuery to perform basic math function as well as adding additional rows to a table dynamically. So far I have this piece of code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".sub").focusout(
        function() {
          $("#net").html('');
          var gross = $("#gross").val();
          var tare = $("#tare").val();
          var net = (gross - tare);
          $("#net").html(Math.round(net * 1000) / 1000);
        });

      $("#add").click(function() {
        $('#lineItemTable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#lineItemTable tbody>tr:last');
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
```

And my html looks like this:

```
<body>
  <a id="add">add Line</a>
  <table id="lineItemTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Gross</th>
      <th>Tare</th>
      <th style="padding-right: 10px">Net Weight</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row_to_clone">
      <td>
        <input type='number' step="any" name='gross' id='gross' class='sub' />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='number' step="any" name='tare' id='tare' class='sub' />
      </td>
      <td id="calculated">
        <p id='net' class='sub1'></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Now, before adding another row to the table, the basic math function works, but the math function does not works for the new added row after I click the `add Line` button. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are violating `html` rules basically by `cloning` elements with `id`. According to `html` rules the `id`s in the DOM should be **`unique`**. So what I suggest is, change `id` to `class` and make use of `$(this)` to fetch correct elements as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hgt9s8vf/1/)**

Your updated **html** would be as follows:

```
<a id="add">add Line</a>
<table id="lineItemTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Gross</th>
      <th>Tare</th>
      <th style="padding-right: 10px">Net Weight</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="row_to_clone">
      <td>
        <input type='number' step="any" name='gross' class='gross sub' /> 
        <!-- Remove id and add it as class-->
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type='number' step="any" name='tare' class='net sub' />
        <!-- Remove id and add it as class-->
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class='net'></p>
        <!-- Remove id and add it as class-->
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and **JS** would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".sub").focusout( //get it using class
        function() {
            var parent=$(this).closest('.row_to_clone'); //find its parent first
            parent.find(".net").html(''); //then get all those elements with necessary class belonging to its parent
            var gross = parent.find('.gross').val();
            var tare = parent.find('.net').val();
            var net = (gross - tare);
            parent.find(".net").html(Math.round(net * 1000) / 1000);
        });

      $("#add").click(function() {
        var newRow=$('#lineItemTable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#lineItemTable tbody>tr:last');
        newRow.find('input').val(''); //Comment this if you you want to persist the value
        newRow.find('p').text('');//Comment this if you you want to persist the value
        return false;
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a function and have to call it again after inserting the html. The new html is not in the DOM when you call the site:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

function do_math() {
          $("#net").html('');
          var gross = $("#gross").val();
          var tare = $("#tare").val();
          var net = (gross - tare);
          $("#net").html(Math.round(net * 1000) / 1000);
        });


$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".sub").focusout(
      do_math();        

);

      $("#add").click(function() {
        $('#lineItemTabletbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#lineItemTable tbody>tr:last');
do_math();        
return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
```